# Peculiar struct type

Tags: c, struct, microchip

So I was reviewing the Microchip's dsPIC MCU header file and stumbled upon this construct:

```
/* Generic structure of entire SFR area for each UART module */
typedef struct tagUART {
        uint16_t uxmode;
        uint16_t uxsta;
        uint16_t uxtxreg;
        uint16_t uxrxreg;
        uint16_t uxbrg;
} UART, *PUART;
```

I cannot seem to figure out what is a type or instance here (and for what end was this designed like that):

1. What is tagUART?
2. What is UART?
3. What is *PUART?

Comment: /questions/252780/why-should-we-typedef-a-struct-so-often-in-c -- first hit searching for "[c] typedef struct".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a kind of *all-in-one* form of

```
struct tagUART { // the structure itself with all its details
        uint16_t uxmode;
        uint16_t uxsta;
        uint16_t uxtxreg;
        uint16_t uxrxreg;
        uint16_t uxbrg;
};

typedef struct tagUART UART; // UART is a shorter name for struct tagUART
typedef struct tagUART *PUART; // PUART is a pointer-type to such a struct
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is tagUART?

It's the name of the struct.

> What is UART?

It's a typedef/alias for the struct.

> What is *PUART?

It's a typedef/alias for a pointer to the struct.